# Whether the statements regarding the Cauchy Product are true?

Tags: real-analysis

a) Exist a divergent series $ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{n} $ such that series $  (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }1) \odot (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{n})$ is convergent
b) Exist an absolutely convergent series $ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{n} $ such that for every conditionally convergent $ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }a_{n} $ the series $  (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }a_{n}) \odot (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{n})$ is also conditionally convergent
c) Find a series $ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }j_{n} $ which is neutral element for a Cauchy Product, so for each series $ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }a_{n} $ occurs $(\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }a_{n}) \odot (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }j_n)=\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }a_{n} $

a) It is my idea how to do this task, but I am afraid that it is incorrect and I need an assessment of this: $$  (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }1) \odot (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{n})= \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }( \sum_{k=0}^{n} 1 \cdot x_{n-k}) =\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }(x_{n}+x_{n-1}+...+x_{0})=\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{n-1}+...+\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty }x_{0}$$ If $ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty } x_{n}$ is divergent, then also  $\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty } x_{n-1}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty } x_{n-2}$,...,$ \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty } x_{0}$ are divergent and the sum of divergent series is divergent so
there is no such series which meets the requirements of the task
b),c) Unfortunately I don't have an idea how to deal it and I am really asking for some tips to do this tasks

Comment: Can you explain what your symbol with a circle and a dot inside means?

Comment: $\odot$ is a Cauchy Product for me and dot inside means ordinary multiplication how for example $2\cdot2=4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(c) The series $1+0+0+0+\dots$ is neutral.

(b) Are you asking if there *exists* a series $\sum_n x_n$ for which this is true? If so, just let $\sum_n x_n$ be the neutral series from part (c).
  If you are instead asking if this is true for *every* series $\sum_n x_n$, the answer is also yes. See [Merten's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens'_theorem).

(a) The argument you wrote does not really work out.

It is true that no such series $\sum_n x_n$ exists. Suppose that the Cauchy product of $\sum_n x_n$ and $\sum_n 1$ is $\sum_n y_n$. You can show that this implies that $x_0=y_0$, and for all $n\ge 1$, $x_n=y_n-y_{n-1}$. This means that $\sum_n x_n$ is telescoping, so that $\sum_n x_n=\lim_n y_n$, provided this limit exists. As long as $\sum y_n$ converges, you will have $\lim_n y_n=0$, so $\sum_n x_n$ converges; therefore, it is impossible to have $\sum_n x_n$ diverging and $\sum_n y_n$ converging.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand how you know that in (a) $x_0=y_0$ and for all $n\ge1, x_{n}=y_{n}-y_{n-1}$. Could you explain?

Comment: @MP3129 $y_n = x_0+x_1+\dots+x_n$, and $y_{n-1}=x_0+x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}$. Therefore, $y_n-y_{n-1}=\dots$.